# count() in neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I recently started with neo4j. I am having trouble with `COUNT()` function.
My nodes have a label say 'consumers' and All consumers nodes have a property called 'status' which can have two values 'active' or 'inactive.'
I want to count call consumer nodes as well as all nodes where `consumers.status = "active"` in a single query.
I have tried `match (n:Consumers) return count(n), count(n) where consumer.status="active"`

I have tried to use 'where' clause in different places  like before return and count with condition using 'as' but it doesn't work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i tried 'match (n:consumers) count(n) as consumerCount with consumerCount, match (n:consumers) where consumers.status ="Active" return consumerCount, count(n) as activeConsumerCount'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
match (n:Consumers) 
return count(n), sum(CASE WHEN consumer.status="active" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as active
```